# Node.js development on android tablet

Tags: android, node.js

I bought an Android tablet with manual keyboard and since the combo seems so ideal for other work, I thought coding with it would enable a pension for my oldish PC computer if the tablet would substitute that approach, too.

Node.js is run on `npm`I suppose, and I have installed a terminal app that enables me using common unix commands.

I found this link:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59863/a-real-terminal-root-or-no-root

stating that terminal would never be like terminal in normal linux e.g. lacking sudo and apt for example.

Any go for a node.js program development then on my machine?

Comment: Is the only possible way to code node on android device to use remote device and sort of remote console connection?

Comment: Have you considered using your tablet's web browser in conjunction with something like Cloud9 to do your development "in the cloud"?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, give it as an answer, please.

I think the right answer to this is kinda workaround in any case. At least according to the lack of other comments and poor views count.

Comment: Remote Desktop allows access to any Windows machine, if a remote access is the only way. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android&hl=fi Completed with cygwin there is a near to unix experience ;)

Comment: Even if you manage to install NPM on android, you will quickly run into dead-end with many modules not compiling on Android. Some frequently used modules often have edge cases for different OS'es. Even Windows is often neglected, you can only imagine how many developers though of Android :)

Comment: I know you hate link-only answers, but let us look what this guy has done: http://www.codemonkeez.com/2014/05/how-i-got-nodejs-and-mongodb-running-on.html . So, on hacking the device to a debian box does the trick. Ok, well you can use the HW for coding now, but maybe as android tablet with store etc, not anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a "workaround".  Sign up for a cloud based IDE such as [Cloud9](https://c9.io).  Then you can use the web browser on your tablet.  The source code can be stored on GitHub, or your own private git repository, and tested and run on the cloud9 servers.  You get a command line interface to your VM where you can do your git and npm things.

I find it nearly unuseable on my old, slow Nook tablet with the screen keyboard, though I can log in and browse code.  On a newer tablet with a real keyboard it should be acceptable.  Let us know how it works for you, or if you find another cloud based IDE you prefer to Cloud9, which looks good to me but is the only one I really tested.

Comment: I have to take a closer look on cloud solutions available around for node.js development. This seems the way I'll go. I still wait the bounty a little bit further, you never know what will come before the time ends. I am eager to see.

Comment: I'm interested in what you end up doing.

Comment: This was more like some pre-requisite information gathering for an NGO-project, so I don't test this immediately. This way still seems so promising and other ways so discouraging, that I suppose this is the path I'll follow. I comment here when some day sth real happens on this. Longest waiting from answer to real test is one year for me, so I did not want to wait until there, and the bounty also set some limits on timing.

Comment: What I ended up doing was my own server behind public ip, kinda same solution as you say but own hardware. I use ssh to connect it and programming is now made inside ssh terminal app. Any app ides available  on android aren't capable enough for npm usage.

Answer (score 2):

There is an App for npm and node runtime in Google Play 
[Dory - Node.js](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.tempage.dorynode)

Comment: Dory works as code runner, it needs a separate editor, at least I could not find one.

Comment: If you are looking for autocompleting, debug and basic IDE features... I think the Android plateform is not ready yet... But if you just need a code editor try DroidEdit instead... I used to code on my phone before getting my first PC so i'm a bit experienced in this field XD

Answer (score 1):

I second the Cloud (c9.io) approach for when you've got a large screen, a decent keyboard, and a great network. But quite a lot of the time I don't and I want to try something with node and then I've got to start up a PC to do so. Your question leads me to believe that you're looking for offline android use of nodejs and npm. Though obviously you'll need to be online to bring in packages and run 'apt update' and the like.

I just started using and liking [Termux](https://termux.com/) for an older Android tablet and it works very well. I found this [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-node-js-application-on-android-part-1-termux-vim-and-node-js-dfa90c28958f#.l57q3gfrs) tutorial and followed along. So far so good. I can't say I care for the soft keyboard. I use a separate Bluetooth keyboard and the whole setup works great for a long airplane flight when I don't have a laptop with me.

Termux itself is a free download and I've used it to install and run some pretty involved v6.5.0 work and so far haven't run across any problems with packages. There's an additional pay-app that adds styles; a few comments seem to be you don't need them but it's a nice way to tip-the-hat to the Termux developer. I'm starting to agree... the emulator is pretty impressive.

Answer (score 0):

I   have used `cloud 9` on `android` and it works great. Also you don't need to use git hub as the repository you can  also  use Bit Bucket which is private by default. And fully integrated with `cloud9`. you can then also use codeship for continuous delivery/integration and deploy  automatically to `heroku`.